# Use googletest with a function that gets input from user via std::cin?

Tags: c++, iostream, googletest, cin

How can I use googletest to test a function that relies on user input via std::cin?

For the example below, I'm looking for whatever code would allow me to add "2\n" to the std::cin stream so that the readUserInput() function reads 2 into the value variable and doesn't require any input from the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int readUserInput()
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> value;

    return value;
}

TEST(cin_test, Basic)
{
    // need code here to define "2\n"
    // as the next input for std::cin

    ASSERT_EQ(readUserInput(), 2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an argument to your function:

```
int readUserInput(std::istream& input)
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    input >> value;
    return value;
}

TEST(Some, Test) {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("someFile", std::ifstream::in);
    // in production code pass std::cin
    std::cout << "readUserInput from std::cin: " << readUserInput(std::cin) << std::endl;
    // in testing pass some mock data from the file (or whatever)
    std::cout << "readUserInput from ifs: " << readUserInput(ifs) << std::endl;
    ifs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL:DR

Assuming you will go through JetBrains unit testing tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/unit-testing-tutorial.html#adding-framework

`MyLib/TaskTwo.cpp`

```cpp
//Write a program reading integers until zero is entered and printing the length of the longest sequence of consecutive numbers of the same value (and this value).


#include "TaskTwoResult.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TaskTwo { ;
public:
    TaskTwo() {

    }

    TaskTwoResult getLongestSequence(istream &std_input,
                                     ostream &std_output,
                                     ostream &result_output) {
        int largestToken = 0;
        int largestTokenOccurences = 0;
        int currentToken = 0;
        int currentOccurences = 0;

        std_output << "Please enter an integer value or enter 0 to stop" << endl;

        while (true) {
            int token = 0;
            std_output << "Enter value:";
            std_input >> token;
            if (token == 0) {
                result_output << "Longest sequence: " << largestTokenOccurences << " times " << largestToken;
                return {
                    largestToken,
                    largestTokenOccurences
                };
            }

            const bool isNewToken = token != currentToken;
            if (isNewToken) {
                currentToken = token;
                currentOccurences = 1;
            } else {
                currentOccurences++;
            }

            if (currentOccurences > largestTokenOccurences) {
                largestTokenOccurences = currentOccurences;
                largestToken = currentToken;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

#### `Google_Test/MyTests.cpp`

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "TaskTwo.cpp"

using namespace std;



//This is just a group -> test name so it will later be reflected in your IDE unit testing window as a tree:
// getLongestSequence
//   | - Test1
//   | - Test2
//   | - Test3
TEST(getLongestSequence, Test1){
    //for input: 22 22 22 22 3 3 3 2 -6 -6 -6 0
    string test_input = "22\n22\n22\n22\n3\n3\n3\n2\n-6\n-6\n-6\n0";
    string expected = "Longest sequence: 4 times 22";

    stringstream fake_input(test_input);
    ostringstream fake_output;
    ostringstream fake_result_output;

    TaskTwoResult result = TaskTwo().getLongestSequence(fake_input, fake_output, fake_result_output);

    string actual = fake_result_output.str();
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, actual);
}
```

### See also:

- Source code: https://github.com/konradbartecki/cpp-stdin-out-tests
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/unit-testing-tutorial.html#adding-framework
- This post is also available on my blog: https://bartecki.me/blog/cpp-testing-std-input-output

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can create a pipe and then swap the `stdin` fd with the "read" end of the pipe. This allows you to write into the pipe and then `std::cin` will read from the pipe instead of actual `stdin`.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

int readUserInput()
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> value;

    return value;
}

TEST(cin_test, Basic)
{
    // Create pipe to mock stdin
    int fildes[2];
    int status = pipe(fildes);
    ASSERT_NE(status, -1);

    // Swap `stdin` fd with the "read" end of the pipe
    status = dup2(fildes[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    ASSERT_NE(status, -1);

    // Create payload
    const char buf[] = "2\n";
    const int bsize  = strlen(buf);

    // Send payload through pipe
    ssize_t nbytes = write(fildes[1], buf, bsize);
    close(fildes[1]);
    ASSERT_EQ(nbytes, bsize);

    ASSERT_EQ(readUserInput(), 2);
    close(fildes[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```